# django form dropdown with all users in it

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to create a form which has a dropdown with all users in it. I tried it like this, with no luck.

```
class ContactFilterByClassificationForm(forms.Form):
   kam = forms.ChoiceField(choices=User.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want to use a [`ModelChoiceField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField).

```
class ContactFilterByClassificationForm(forms.Form):
    kam = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```